# Is it ok to use assert on a field I know won't be null?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

From reading existing posts I have come to learn that "assert" should not be used in production code, however IntelliJ's first tip for me when using a method I know won't be NULL, but is still Nullable in other ways, is to tell me that I should use "assert"
[image: IntelliJ screenshot of tooltip]

In the above code ItemMeta will not be null when creating a new ItemStack however it can be null if ItemStack is also null, which is why it doesn't have the @NotNull annotation to begin with.

Knowing this, what is the most correct way to handle this Warning? Is it to ignore it because I know it will never be null, or is it to still do a null check. If it is to do a null check which kind, assert or the way I was doing already which is

```
if(fillerMeta != null)
```

Comment: You should use `Objects.requireNonNull`

Comment: What is the purpose to check possible NPE  on every place when it can happen? What value will you get if you add it? What is the difference? If you add assert on this particular place like "requireNotNull", you will get a message during run time that value is null. If you don't use assert or "requireNotNull" on this place, you will get NPE. Both mean basically the same. So what is the purpose on adding assert *in this particular* place of code? I see no advantages. But disadvantages are obvious: The code will be bloated with asserts, not readable, hard to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have come to learn that "assert" should not be used in production code

That's *very* debatable. If you're asserting `fillerMeta != null`, you're saying this can't be null or something is seriously wrong with my code.

That's perfectly fine. But you need to be careful if you want to assert something, or error handle something. Asserting something like `1 + 1 == 2` is fine, because if it turns out math doesn't work that way, all other assumptions you made are probably out of the window too. Thus it's fine for the program to just explode.

If `fillerMeta` could be null because it was for example returned from a function you think might return `null` you should do error handling instead. E.g. `if (fillerMeta == null) throw new Exception...` and gracefully handle that.

Comment: `if (fillerMeta == null) throw new NullPointerException("fillerMeta")` is probably more helpful than a plain old NPE somewhere later.

Answer (score 0):

If `fillerMeta` is something that you cannot handle if it's null, or if it being null is something that can no longer allow your specific function to run, use `Objects.requireNotNull`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` if `fillerMeta` ends up being null. Otherwise, if it being null doesn't impact your program in a large way, just step around it with an `if (fillerMeta != null)`

Answer (score 0):

More of an addendum:

> is to tell me that I should use "assert"

No, the suggestion is to "Assert not null". A bit of guessing here, but I assume that IntelliJ wouldn't insert an `assert()` statement here, but either

- `Objects.reqireNotNull()` which would throw an NPE or
- some guarding if/else structure to enable you to explicitly write code for the two possible cases

From that point of view: just go forward and have Intellij "improve" your code. See what it does, and if you don't like that, simply undo.